# Angular 2 update component variable with http service promise

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Im currently learning angular 2 and typescript which seems to be going well so far but i am having a bit of trouble getting my service i created to update the array in the component i call it in although all the data from the service is display fine in the ng-for in my template.

```
    ***people-service.ts***

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the PeopleService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  load() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://api.randomuser.me/?page=3&results=30')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          data = data.results;
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

Above is the service i created that returns the json data in a promise from the api.

```
***about.ts***
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PeopleService } from '../../providers/people-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-about',
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    providers: [PeopleService]
})
export class AboutPage {

    public people: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public peopleService: PeopleService) {
        this.peopleService.load().then(data => {
            this.people = data;
        });
        console.log(this.people);
    }
}
```

In the above component load the data in my constructor which displays in the template fine like i said but the console.log(this.people) shows undefined I hope someone can help me figure out what im missing here. I imagine i must be doing something wrong with the way the data is being returned from the service or the point i am trying to log the data. For anyone interested the main goal of this is to do `this.people / 2` to get the middle object within the array and scrollTo it when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.peopleService.load()` is an asynchronous function, this means:

1. The `load()` function gets executed
2. The `console.log` gets executed
3. `data` returns from the serer and `this.people = data` is executed.

You want to put the `console.log` inside the `load()` callback function, where `this.people = data` is set, so you can print the actual data, like this:

```
this.peopleService.load().then(data => {
    this.people = data;
    console.log(this.people);
});
```

Comment: so i do everything within the load method then like this         this.peopleService.load().then(data => {
            this.people = data;
            console.log(this.people);
            this.middleMan = this.people / 2
        });

Comment: In short, yes, but it would be cleaner if you put the logic to handle responses in a seperate function and just call that from `.then()`.

Comment: Ok make sense then i can just call the function each time thank you so much for your help i just though this.people = data would be available anywhere in the component thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid wrapping Observables into Promises, or Promises to Observables and write your service methods so they return an Observable. (Unless you have a really good reason not to :)

```
@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  load() {
    // DON'T 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://api.randomuser.me/?page=3&results=30')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          data = data.results;
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
    // DO: 
    return this.http.get('http://api.randomuser.me/?page=3&results=30')
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

}
```

In service you set up a way to get the data, and in your component (where you actually need the data) you *subscribe* to the observable returned by the service to get the data:

```
export class AboutPage {
    public people: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public peopleService: PeopleService) {
        this.peopleService.load().subscribe(data => {
            this.people = data;
            console.log(this.people);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave this a try but totally breaks it within my template Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. What is the downside of wrapping Observables into Promises?

Comment: That error probably means you are getting Object from server, and you're expecting an array (as ngFor does). Add `.do(console.log)` after *.map()* and check what your data is. You can then chain other map/filter/reduce etc operators to transform the data to what you want/need.

Comment: Downside is that you're doing same thing twice: `Promise.then(data => {})` vs `Observable.subscribe(data => {})` It's kinda the same.. But promises execute once, observable can stream data. Observable is not executed until you subscribe to it, Promise is executed immediately. Many other differences, I suggest you do some reading (;

Comment: I will thank you i am struggling the get my head round observables and promises i will play around and see what i can come up with also

Comment: Have it working now and have a better understanding of using it from this article http://coenraets.org/blog/2016/02/angular2-ionic2-data-services-promises-observables/ had to change it to `this.people = data.results` no idea what you ment by `.do(console.log)` as the property "do" doesnt seem to exists on a Observable.